# Copying tab-delimited data out of the shell

Tags: shell, osx, python, printing, spreadsheet

I already posted this on [askdifferent](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/314092/copying-tab-delimited-data-from-terminal-to-excel), but no luck. Glad to remove if out of scope.

---

So I am running some Python scripts that print out tab-delimited data (i.e. adding the `\t` character during the `print` command).

#### Problem

- I am trying to copy that tab-delimited data from the shell / Terminal into Excel Mac or other spreadsheet applications, hoping they would recognize the tab-delimination and put the items into separate cells

This does not work; however, if I copy the text into an editor such as Atom or Emacs first, and then into Excel, it recognizes the tabs as delimiters.

- Why does it work with the additional step?
- Do the text editors change the nature of the tabs, and how can I emulate this behavior within the Terminal?

#### Example:

```
print "123\tbeetle\t12.4\n200\tbutterfly\t1.2\n"
```

Result:

Copy from Terminal into Excel:

[image: Copy into Excel directly]

Copy from Terminal to Text Editor, then into Excel:

[image: Copy via Text Editor]

Any help is much appreciated! I know there are more elegant ways of doing this, but this is still something I'd like to figure out.

I found a somewhat similar, but unresolved question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45485302/copy-paste-tab-delimited-results-into-excel-file).

Running Python 2.7.13 , Sierra 10.12.6, Excel 2016 for Mac

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's presumably a limitation of your terminal application. In comparison, tabs copy fine from my (Linux) terminal. Perhaps you could try a different emulator? (I've heard good things about [iTerm2](https://www.iterm2.com).)

Alternatively, you could directly pipe into the clipboard. I believe the command on OS X is `pbcopy`. i.e.

```
print "123\tbeetle\t12.4\n200\tbutterfly\t1.2\n" | pbcopy
```

Comment: `pbcopy` totally does it. Thank you for your help!